# How to combine Mongo $in and $cond

Tags: mql

I have a collection that looks something like this like this (each array element is 1 document):

```json
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "title": "title",
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": 41,
                "name": "test 1"
            },
            {
                "_id": 42,
                "name": "test 2"
            },
            {
                "_id": 43,
                "name": "test 3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "title": "title 2",
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": 44,
                "name": "test 4"
            },
            {
                "_id": 45,
                "name": "test 5"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

What I'd like to do is filter out all documents using `$redact` where data._id is `$in` an array of `[41, 42]`. So, if data._id is ever equal to 41 or 42, the whole document should be kept. Else, it should be pruned.

```
{
    $cond: {
        if: {
            $in: [
                "$data._id",
                [ 41, 42 ]
            ]
        },
        then: "$$KEEP",
        else: "$$PRUNE"
    }
}
```

However, the query above doesn't return anything when I use the `$redact` stage in Compass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the $redact aggregation, apart from that the query looks fine https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

```
{ 
  $redact: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $in: [
          "$data._id",
          [ 41, 42 ]
        ]
      },
      then: "$$KEEP",
      else: "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }
}
```